# How to query cached plans that contain a specific missing index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, plan-cache, sp-blitzcache

I see a potential missing index for a table but would like to first query all cached plans that have that specific missing index (so I can later test those queries after the new index is built). How do you do build such a query?  Can sp_blitzcache help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't foolproof by any means but as a rough sanity check you can use the following query that leverages the [**DMVs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-ver15) to filter on the cached plan text's table name and index name that you plan to index:

```
SELECT 
    PlanText.[dbid] AS DatabaseId,
    DB_NAME(PlanText.[dbid]) AS DatabaseName,
    CachedPlans.plan_handle AS PlanHandle, 
    OBJECT_NAME(PlanText.objectid) AS ObjectName, 
    CachedPlans.objtype AS ObjectType, 
    CachedPlans.refcounts AS CachedPlanReferenceCount, 
    CachedPlans.usecounts AS CachedPlanUseCount, 
    PlanText.[text] AS QueryText
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS CachedPlans
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CachedPlans.plan_handle) AS PlanText
WHERE PlanText.[text] LIKE '%YourTableName%'
    AND PlanText.[text] LIKE '%YourColumnToBeIndexed%'
```

This leverages the DMVs [`sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`sys.dm_exec_sql_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
Just replace the wildcard filters above with your table name and index. This will give you the actual query that the cached plan is for, so then you can re-test it after you create the index. I also included some potentially helpful columns like `DatabaseName`, `CachedPlanReferenceCount` (how many objects reference this cached plan), and `CachedPlanUseCount` (how many times this plan was used). So you could theoretically add an `ORDER BY CachedPlanUseCount DESC` clause to get the most popularly used queries too and prioritize your list.

One reason why this isn't perfect is if the query in the `QueryText` column contains a different column coincidentally with the same name as the one you're indexing, but from a different table, and therefor will be a *false positive* match.

Answer (score 2):

To do this reliably you will need to upgrade to SQL Server 2019 and use the brand new DMV

sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats_query

There is a sample query with the documentation, I just became aware of this yesterday on Erik's blog.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-groups-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/documentation-for-dm_db_missing_index_group_stats_query/

Comment: oOo nice, this is a good DMV to be aware of, thanks!